# How can I check if a DNN template editor token is empty or not?

Tags: jquery, html, token, dotnetnuke

I have a form where people can enter information, and each field has a token. For example if someone enters their name in a textbox labeled name, if I use the [NAME] token, that will output the entered name on another page.

I am now building the page that will output the information entered in the form

Name: Name entered`<span>Name: </span>[NAME]`

and was wondering how I can check if the token [NAME] if empty or not, and if the field was empty, to remove the  element.

Thank you

Comment: Is this a custom module that you've built or are you just sticking the Tokens into an HTML module instance?

Comment: Hi, I am not familiar with the latter option, but it is not a custom module, so I am assuming the latter is correct.

Comment: Where is the form coming from, if not from a custom module?

Comment: The module I am using generates a form, and outputs the information using the same module. The template editor is part of the module as well.

Comment: What module are you using that generates the form?

Comment: The module is called: DNN events planner module

Comment: I'm looking at the documentation for this module. I don't see any token for [NAME]. I see [EVENTNAME] and [FIRSTNAME], etc. Which template are you referring to?

Comment: Hi, I was just giving a generic example. In this case I would be using [FIRSTNAME], since that is not a required field to complete the form.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - there doesn't seem to be any built-in way to do conditional formatting on Token Replacement.  There have been some thoughts about extending Token Replacement (http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/154432/templating-or-the-art-of-making-complicated-things-simple), but you would have to modify the Events Planner Module in order to do this, and would be a lot of work.

As a sort of hack, I might suggest the following:

```
 <span id="spnNameLabel">Name: </span><span id="spnNameText">[NAME]</span>
 <script language="javascript">
      if (document.getElementById("spnNameText").innerHTML == "") {
           document.getElementById("spnNameLabel").style.display = "none";
      }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'll give it a try immediately. On another note, if I had another token, lets say [EMAIL], that I used to hyperlink the name:  <span id="spnNameLabel">Name: </span><span id="spnNameText"><a href="[EMAIL]">[NAME]</a></span>, if the email is left blank, but the name is provided, how can I remove the hyperlink property, as if this was done, it will open a blank page.

Comment: Give the anchor tag an ID too, and check the Href attribute of it in your javascript function.